# Using datetime.time for comparison and column creation

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've been using Pandas for a while and I'm sure it's a dumb question.

I need to create a column in a data frame which is conditional to the datetime.time. If datetime.time < 12, fill column with 'morning', then the same process to 'afternoon' and 'night'.

```
import datetime

b['time'] = ['01-01-2000 10:00:00', '01-01-2000 15:00:00', '01-01-2000 21:00:00']

b['time'].dt.time

(output)
1   10:00:00
2   15:00:00
3   21:00:00

b['time'].dt.time < 12 #example

TypeError: can't compare datetime.time to int
```

Question is: I can't compare datetime.time to int. How can I fix this?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Is not possible compare hours? Can you add data sample and desired output?

Comment: Sample added. The desired output would be something like a True/False series.

Comment: then use `b['time'].dt.hour< 12`

Comment: Gosh, I knew it was dumb...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) or [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) for labels by bins:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=24, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng})  

bins = [0, 5, 13, 17, 25]
labels = ['Morning','Afternoon','Evening','Night']
hours = df['Date'].dt.hour
df['bin'] = pd.cut(hours-5+24 *(hours<5),bins=bins,labels=labels,right=False)
```

---

```
bins = [-1,4,9,17,21]
labels = ['Night', 'Morning','Afternoon','Evening','Night']
df['bin1']  = np.array(labels)[np.array(bins).searchsorted(hours)-1]                     
print (df)
                  Date        bin       bin1
0  2017-04-03 00:00:00      Night      Night
1  2017-04-03 01:00:00      Night      Night
2  2017-04-03 02:00:00      Night      Night
3  2017-04-03 03:00:00      Night      Night
4  2017-04-03 04:00:00      Night      Night
5  2017-04-03 05:00:00    Morning    Morning
6  2017-04-03 06:00:00    Morning    Morning
7  2017-04-03 07:00:00    Morning    Morning
8  2017-04-03 08:00:00    Morning    Morning
9  2017-04-03 09:00:00    Morning    Morning
10 2017-04-03 10:00:00  Afternoon  Afternoon
11 2017-04-03 11:00:00  Afternoon  Afternoon
12 2017-04-03 12:00:00  Afternoon  Afternoon
13 2017-04-03 13:00:00  Afternoon  Afternoon
14 2017-04-03 14:00:00  Afternoon  Afternoon
15 2017-04-03 15:00:00  Afternoon  Afternoon
16 2017-04-03 16:00:00  Afternoon  Afternoon
17 2017-04-03 17:00:00  Afternoon  Afternoon
18 2017-04-03 18:00:00    Evening    Evening
19 2017-04-03 19:00:00    Evening    Evening
20 2017-04-03 20:00:00    Evening    Evening
21 2017-04-03 21:00:00    Evening    Evening
22 2017-04-03 22:00:00      Night      Night
23 2017-04-03 23:00:00      Night      Night
```